# String.match return incorrect when passed a manually created RegExp object?

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer, google-chrome

Let's say I have this regexp

```
(^|;)[\s]*style=([^;]*)
```

And a string to match against

```
test=en; style=night
```

According to the [MDN documentation for String.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

- I can pass in a regexp literal - `/(^|;)[\s]*style=([^;]*)/`
- I can pass a string, which is wrapped in a RegExp object - `"(^|;)[\s]*style=([^;]*)"`
- Or I can pass in a RegExp object created - `new RegExp("(^|;)[\s]*style=([^;]*)")`

The problem is that they do not all evaluate to the same value.

```
/(^|;)[\s]*style=([^;]*)/ => array of matches
"(^|;)[\s]*style=([^;]*)" => null
new RegExp("(^|;)[\s]*style=([^;]*)") => null
```

**What is going on in this case? Why don't they all evaluate to the same set of matches?**

BTW. Tested on Chrome 38.0.2125.101 and IE 11.0.9600.17278

Comment: If you pass a string to RegExp constructor you have to double-escape special characters.

Comment: `new RegExp("(^|;)\\s*style=([^;]*)")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When using the constructor function, the normal string escape rules
>   (preceding special characters with \ when included in a string) are
>   necessary. For example, the following are equivalent:

```
var re = /\w+/;
var re = new RegExp("\\w+");
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: Such an obvious error to make. I was convinced I found a bug! Missed that backslash every time I looked at it. Thanks!